# Docker Image for IBM websphere Liberty and Licensing

Tags: docker, websphere-liberty

I am new to IBM websphere, and I have a requirement i need to use Docker Image websphere Liberty ( only Liberty ) for Production Env, i am not sure which image i have to pick for production purpose.

**Official Github Repo lists:**
Docker Hub images
There are two different supported WebSphere Liberty Docker image sets available on Docker Hub:

Our recommended set here. These are images using Red Hat's Universal Base Image as the Operating System and are re-built daily. direct to this image [https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/websphere-liberty][1]
Other sets can be found here. These are re-built automatically anytime something changes in the layers below. There are tags with different combinations of Java and Operating System versions. direct to this Image [https://hub.docker.com/_/websphere-liberty][1]

Also, how Image will be licensed if we choose one for Production ENV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As illustrated in the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/WASdev/ci.docker#docker-hub-images) you mentioned, either of these sets of images can be used in production as-is, as long as you have the proper entitlement.

If you want to apply a license to it, please see [this page](https://github.com/WASdev/ci.docker/tree/master/ga/production-upgrade#using-websphere-liberty-docker-in-production) which outlines the steps you can take to create a new image with the license applied.